# JQuery .show() after replacing html erases styling in MVC 4 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an empty div:

```
<div id="reportBody"></div>
```

with simple css:

```
#reportBody {
   height: 100%;
}
```

The reportBody div is in a hidden modal that is called on button click. Using jquery/ajax to call the controller to build an iframe string to an SSRS report.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dashboardReportForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                BrewerySelect: {
                    required: true
                },
                LineSelect: {
                    required: true
                },
                datepicker: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                }
            },
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                element.after(error);
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var brewery = document.getElementById('BrewerySelect').value;
                var line = document.getElementById('LineSelect').value;
                var day = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
                var url = '@Url.Action("GetUrl")';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { breweryCode: brewery, packageLine: line, date: day },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var url = '<iframe src="' + data + '" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>';
                        $('#reportBody').html(url).show();                           
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('document.ready() dashboardReportForm.validate method failed');
                    }
                });
                ResetStyle();
                $('#reportModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
```

It is the $('#reportBody').html(url).show();  in that code that replaces the inner html of the div. When I hardcode the iframe and skip this method it displays perfectly. When I use this method it breaks, the height: 100% does not show in chromes tools after inspecting at all.

How do I prevent this from happening or, failing that, reinsert it in the same method.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is that CSS?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve]. Adding a code snippet or JS Fiddle would be a good idea too.

Comment: @Gothdo, it's in a seperate site.css file.

Comment: Also, I'll work in a fiddle when I have just a bit more time. Maybe 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: Hard code the style into the div.

```
<div id="reportBody" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```